# Add a title and display item cost and total item cost on WooCommerce checkout review order table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, price

I understand that the title of my question might sound confusing and therefore, I ask you to look at the attached image for clarification.

[image]

---

I've tried myself to make this work without success. Testing my code changes nothing on the checkout page. No change, no error, no notices - nothing.

My code so far:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'item_price_and_total_price', 10, 3 );
function item_price_and_total_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){    
        $item = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
    }

    // item price title
    $price_title = 'Item price';

    // item price (this should not change as the qty changes)
    $price_per_item = wc_price( $item ) . ' per item';

    // total item price (cost) as the qty changes
    $total_item_price = // don't know how to get it

    // return everything
    $price = $price_title . '<br />' . $price_per_item . '<br />' . $total_item_price;

    return $price;
}
```

---

Someone who can tell me where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could use the `woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal` hook instead.
- The use of a `foreach` loop is not necessary
- Notice the use of WooCommerce [Conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/): `is_checkout()` - Returns true on the checkout page
- Optional: `$cart_item['quantity'];` can be used if necessary to provide additional conditions based on the product quantity

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal( $subtotal, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Returns true on the checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() ) {  
         // Item price title
        $price_title = 'Item price';
        
        // Item price
        $item_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
        
        // Line subtotal
        $line_subtotal = $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
        
        // Item title + item price
        $subtotal = '<span>' . $price_title . '</span>' . wc_price( $item_price );
        
        // Append to
        $subtotal .= wc_price( $line_subtotal );
    }

    return $subtotal;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I made a few changes to the code, adding a new line between the title and the total including text to indicate that change. Thank you for adding explanations along the way. I keep on learning.